# Thank-you letters WYSIWYG vs html source content

Tags: system-workflow-messages, wysiwyg

Drupal 7.72
Civi 5.24.5

I recently added an IF statement to our receipts and Thank-You letters to comply with Florida Charity Regulations. The state of FL requires us to have a statement on our receipts for donors from FL. So I did a IF 'FL' then... It works with the System Workflow Templates for online and offline receipts. However, for checks we send a Thank-You Letter as a receipt. That kinda works. The difference I see is, the Thank-You letter has a WYSIWYG with it but the System Workflow Template online/offline does not. The WYSIWYG shows {if $stateProv eq 'FL'} but the html source has {if $stateProv eq & #39;FL& #39;} (I added spaces so it displays without converting to ')  If I change the html source to {if $stateProv eq 'FL'} it works but even though we check "Update Template" it still needs to have this changed every time we use the Thank-You letter template.

1. How do I fix the Thank-You letter?
2. Where do I find the WYSIWYG settings in CiviCRM? I tried to find where to disable that or even find what WYSIWYG we are using so I could Google a fix to make '' stick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off html encoding for CKeditor through UI

Navigate to Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Display preferences

Scroll down until you see `Configure CkEditor` button. Click on it to view all the settings. Under Advance options add `entities` option as `False`(as shown in image) and save the form.

[image]

**Note: You will need to clear your browser cache to reflect the changes(and CiviCRM caches).**

If you want to turn off the ck-editor completely for whole site than you can switch to text area. You need to navigate it to CiviCRM >> Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Display preferences. Change value for Wysiwig Editor from ckeditor to text area.

HTH

Pradeep